# Multiple nested redirects in Router v4 (Vue 3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm migrating from `vue2` to `vue3` and when it comes to switching from `Router v3` to `Router v4` my route redirects stop working as expected and I can't see how to fix it after digging through the docs.

Here is an example.

Using the router below, and a starting url as `http://localhost:8080/app` but I'll omit `http://localhost:8080` to be short:

**Router v3 behaviour (expected):**

- `/app` -> redirects to `/app/dashboard`
- `/app/dashboard` -> redirects to `/app/dashboard/list`

So after entering `/app` user ends up at `/app/dashboard/list` which is expected

**Router v4 behaviour (incorrect):**

- `/app` -> redirects to `/dashboard/list`
- then not found as there is no such route in my app

I'm not sure what's going on here as I wasn't able to find any mentions of such a change in the docs or how to fix it. It seems like it takes the final redirect route and changes the full path, instead of only changing the path's components of it's level, but that's just my speculation.

**The question**:

How do I make Router v4 respect all the intermediate redirects and make it to only change the intended part of the path, not the whole path?

**Here is my router setup:**

```
let routerOptions = {
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [

        {
            path: '/app',
            name: 'AppMain',
            component: MainLayout,
            redirect:'/app/dashboard',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    component: DashboardMainPage,
                    redirect: 'dashboard/list',
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'list',
                            name: 'DashboardListRoute',
                            component: DashboardListPage,
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'calendar',
                            name: 'DashboardCalendarRoute',
                            component: DashboardCalendarPage,
                        },

                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    ],

}

let router = createRouter(routerOptions)
```